# Oracle Apex 20.1. Report with 'Cards' template, how to redirect to another page on click a card?

Tags: javascript, html, oracle, oracle-apex

I don't really know how to redirect to another page, I specified `CARD_TITLE` and `CARD_DESC` and `CARD_SUBTEXT`, but i don't know how `CARD_LINK` works. Also, I would like to forward a column value to an item on the new page.

Basically, when someone clicks on a card, the goal is to redirect to another page with a column value.

I saw that in APEX 20.2 there is Cards region but in our version there is only the 'Cards' template on a Report region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CARD_LINK` should be a *link* to another page. Create it any way you want, but - I prefer `APEX_URL.GET_URL`

```
select <CARD_... columns here>,
  --
  apex_page.get_url (p_page    => 2,                --> go to page 2
                     p_items   => 'P2_ID',          --> to P2_ITEM ...
                     p_values  => a.id) card_link   --> ... pass a.id column value
from some_table a
where ...
```

At the end, it'll look like e.g.

```
f?p=:2:::::P2_ID:1056
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I didn't know this APEX_URL.GET_URL thing. You helped a lot!